# Why is $m$ used to denote slope?

Tags: notation, analytic-geometry

What is the reason, historically, that the letter $m$ is used to denote the slope of a line?

Comment: In elementary school (later years) in Sweden, $m$ usually denotes the intercept, as you can see here: http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linjär_ekvation

Comment: ‘We designate the slope of a line by m because the word slope starts with the letter m; I know of no better reason.'

Comment: I believe it comes from the phrase modulus of slope.

Comment: For purposes of cross-reference, [this question is also asked on math ed SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12796/explaining-to-students-why-m-and-b-are-used-in-the-slope-intercept-equation).  There are a number of very good answers there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Slope.html), there's no consensus. Some think it may have come from French *monter* meaning *to climb*, but this is just speculation $-$ it's likely just a trend that caught on. The article I linked to contains a greater elaboration and some examples of where it's *not* used.

Comment: See Also: http://jeff560.tripod.com/geometry.html. There is a huge section on slope, and seems to agree that the reason $m$ was chosen is not clear.

Comment: Thank you Clive. I saw the MathWorld page, I was hoping someone knew more than what was written there.

Comment: @Jim: I think that, short of undertaking some hardcore historical analysis, we'll have to make do with the answer that no-one knows the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not known why the letter m was chosen for slope; the choice may have been arbitrary. John Conway has suggested m could stand for "modulus of slope." One high school algebra textbook says the reason for m is unknown, but remarks that it is interesting that the French word for "to climb" is monter. However, there is no evidence to make any such connection. Descartes, who was French, did not use m. In *Mathematical Circles Revisited* (1971) mathematics historian Howard W. Eves suggests "it just happened."

[Source](https://services.math.duke.edu/education/webfeats/Slope/Slopederiv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not a reason, but a lovely coincidence is that the higher dimensional analogue of a slope is a matrix.

$$
\vec{y} = M(\vec{x})
$$

would be the higher dimensional analogue of

$$
y = mx
$$

where $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $M$ is a $n \times m$ matrix.

So I like to think of the "m" as standing for "matrix".