# Why is $m$ used as the variable for slope in slope-intercept form?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, analytic-geometry, math-history, convention

I was wondering if you could answer a question I have on slope intercept form of a linear equation. I know its $y=mx+b$, but *why* is it $mx+b$? Don't get me wrong. I know that $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept and everything, but why is it the letters "$m$" and "$b$"? I understand that they're random numbers, but why couldn't it have been "$a$" and "$b$"?

For example, in standard form, it's $ax+by+c$. They used "$a$", "$b$", and "$c$". Those are sensible numbers. (When I first the slope-intercept form, I thought "$m$" was a special number.) If you are unable to answer this, could I please be referred to a source that might be able to?

Comment: In Denmark the equation is normally written as $y=ax+b$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $m$ used to denote slope?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104317/why-is-m-used-to-denote-slope)

Comment: Also, https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12796/8931

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Tradition.

Long answer: No one really knows.

You might get a lot of folk etymology though.

Other countries use other letters.

Here is an example of a bunch of people discussing it. As you see, they don't get anywhere.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054916/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52477.html)

Comment: Well, which countries *do* use $m$ and which use others? In Germany the $m$-tradition is well-established. Where else? (My untested folk-etymology bet is on Latin *motio*)

Comment: Well Russia uses other letters all over - literally. :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what do you mean? Sorry for necroposting, but I don't get it. They don't use Cyrillic alphabet for variable names at all, if that's what you meant.