# why is the slope of a line denoted by the symbol " m"

Tags: soft-question, analytic-geometry

I think the distance travelled by a body is denoted by " s" because of " ***s***pace" , or even " ***s***patium" in latin.

Is there any reason why the solpe of a line is denoted by " ***m*** " in the equation : $y=mx+b$?

Where does this usage come from?

Comment: Some letter must be used. The use of the letter m became quite influential. Answer me this: why is the letter x so ubiquitous in algebra and even all of mathematics?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) : there is no clear answer to the question why the letter *m* is used for slope.

Comment: There is [a lot of speculation](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/11/slope-symbol.html) online, but I don't think the ultimate reason is known (if there even was one).

Comment: There is some history [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060111143838/http://members.aol.com/jeff570/geometry.html)

Comment: This was a topic of discussion on the MAA History of Mathematics SIG a couple years back.  One line of "folk etymology" is that $ \ m \ $ is for the French _monter_ , "to climb". But in fact, no one seems sure of how that choice was introduced.  As for the use of $ \ x \ $ in algebra, it comes from Vieta, who introduced symbolic algebra, from the ancient legal practice (he was a lawyer as well as a mathematician) that a person whose identity was to be kept unknown or hypothetical was "X" (this survives today in expressions like "Mister X" or "X, The Unknown").

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104317/why-is-m-used-to-denote-slope ? or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548244/why-is-m-used-as-the-variable-for-slope-in-slope-intercept-form ?